# Getting Null check operator used on a null value error when calling in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using this dart package otp_text_field 1.1.1.

```
                     OTPTextField(
                        length: 6,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        fieldWidth: 30,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                        textFieldAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        fieldStyle: FieldStyle.underline,
                        onChanged: (pin) {
                          if (pin.length == 6) {
                            print("Changed: " + pin);
                          }
                        },
                      )
```

I get this error on the onChanged handler

```
The following _CastError was thrown while calling onChanged:
Null check operator used on a null value
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
```

Not getting any idea on whats wrong.

Added Stacktrace -

```
  _OTPTextFieldState.buildTextField.<anonymous closure>
package:otp_text_field/otp_field.dart:179
#1      EditableTextState._formatAndSetValue
package:flutter/…/widgets/editable_text.dart:2298
#2      EditableTextState.updateEditingValue
package:flutter/…/widgets/editable_text.dart:1749
#3      TextInput._handleTextInputInvocation
package:flutter/…/services/text_input.dart:1351
#4      MethodChannel._handleAsMethodCall
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:435
```

Comment: It seems the problem relies inside the package. Can you share the stacktrace (the lines below "this was the stack")?

Comment: @enzo I have added the stacktrace.

Comment: Also if I use onCompleted handler with onChanged I dont see any errors

Comment: Yes, the stacktrace points to [this line](https://github.com/iamvivekkaushik/OTPTextField/blob/master/lib/otp_field.dart#L179) in the package's source code. It only raises when `onCompleted` is null (i.e. you don't pass it as parameter). [A related issue](https://github.com/iamvivekkaushik/OTPTextField/issues/12).

Answer (score 2):

```dart
onChanged: (String? pin) {
  if (pin?.length == 6) { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just provide the `onCompleted` callback to that widget. It is a nullable callback which means its not mandatory to pass that function. But this dependencies call this callback if the length of the top text field matches with the specified length you had provided.